in strawberry perl 5.40.0.1 error when try to install TK
I am trying to install the Tk module on Strawberry Perl 5.40.0.1, but I keep getting a fatal error during the installation.
Here is the procedure I used:

Opened a Strawberry Perl shell.
Ran the command cpan Tk.

However, I get the following error output:
> gcc -c -I. -I./pTk/mTk/xlib  -I.. -I.. -I../pTk/mTk/xlib -I. -Ibitmaps -I.. -I../pTk/mTk/xlib -std=c99 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DMULTIPLICITY -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -DPERLDLL -Os -falign-functions -falign-jumps -falign-labels -falign-loops -freorder-blocks -freorder-blocks-algorithm=stc -freorder-blocks-and-partition   -DVERSION="804.036" -DXS_VERSION="804.036"  "-IC:\\STRAWB\~1\\perl\\lib\\CORE"    imgBMP.c
> cc1.exe: fatal error: imgBMP.c: No such file or directory
> compilation terminated.
> Additional Info

I also tried forcing the installation with the -f flag, but I encountered the same issue.
Is there a way to get a version of Strawberry Perl that already includes a precompiled Tk module? Or, is there another approach I can take to successfully install Tk on Strawberry Perl?

Strawberry Perl 40.0 on Windows 11.
I've GOT the file imgBMP.c, but little good it does me. My error msg:
gcc -c -I. -I./pTk/mTk/xlib  -I.. -I.. -I../pTk/mTk/xlib -I. -Ibitmaps -I.. -I../pTk/mTk/xlib -std=c99 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DMULTIPLICITY -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -DPERLDLL -Os -falign-functions -falign-jumps -falign-labels -falign-loops -freorder-blocks -freorder-blocks-algorithm=stc -freorder-blocks-and-partition   -DVERSION=\"804.036\" -DXS_VERSION=\"804.036\"  "-IC:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE"    imgBMP.c
In file included from ../pTk/mTk/xlib/X11/Xlib.h:31,
             from tkWinPort.h:19,
             from tkPort.h:32,
             from tk.h:87,
             from imgBMP.c:11:
../pTk/mTk/xlib/X11/X.h:182:34: error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant
  182 | #define ControlMask             (1<<2)
  |                                  ^
gmake[1]: *** [makefile:891: imgBMP.o] Error 1

From my Google searching, it appears this error has been happening to people for a while now. Strawberry is completely F'd for me by this. I looked at going back to ActiveState, but they've gone commercial.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
